# Unhandle promise rejection, getting data from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios, unhandled-promise-rejection

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          data: [],
         };
  }
 updateSearch = (e) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey{1234}&number=100`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
      });
  };
   render()
      return(
            <SearchBar  
               placeholder="Search Food..."
               onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
               value={data}
             />
            <List style={{ paddingTop: hp("2%") }}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                {this.state.data.map(({ type }) => (
              <Text>{this.state.type.products.title}</Text>
            ))}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </List>
```

Hey everyone, I'm trying to get data from the Spoonacular database using `axios`, I'm trying to search the food with the `SearchBar` and display the content in the List, I'm new to programming and I'm not very sure of what I'm doing, when I run the code it tells me `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 400]` and nothing shows on the list.

Link to the documentation: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Grocery-Products

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. The request failed, and since you didn't add a `.catch`, the rejection is unhandled. You're probably not requesting the API properly.

Comment: Thanks, I added the `.catch`, but can't figure out what is wrong with the request for the API

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `query` parameter. According to the docs it's required. So a correct request would be something like

```
let query = ...; //get hte value from the searchbar
axios
  .get(
    `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}&apiKey=1234&number=100`
  )
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({ data: res.data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

The body of the erroneus response probably would include a hint ...

Comment: You are right, the problem is that if I insert `query=pizza`, the only results that will show are pizzas, how can I change the query with the input from the `SearchBar`

Comment: I'm not using react or react-native, so I can't help you with how to get the value from the searchbar. But once you got it, you can simply add it to the query like shown above